# UITableView Move row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have some NSMutableArray in tableView which contain class Lesson

```
@interface Lesson : NSObject <NSCoding>{

    NSString *time1;
    NSString *time2;
    NSString *predmet;
    NSString *namPrepod;
    NSString *zamet;
}
```

I move row in tableview................................................................................................................................

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath 
{
    if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
    {
    if(fromIndexPath.section==0)
    {
       NSMutableArray *r = [[Singleton sharedInstance].chetNedel.monday objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row]; 
       [[Singleton sharedInstance].chetNedel.monday  removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
       [[Singleton sharedInstance].chetNedel.monday  insertObject:r atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
    }
    if(fromIndexPath.section==1)
    {
        NSMutableArray *r = [[Singleton sharedInstance].chetNedel.tuesday objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row]; 
        [[Singleton sharedInstance].chetNedel.monday  removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
        [[Singleton sharedInstance].chetNedel.monday  insertObject:r atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
    }
```

but when I move row in program I have got error on this lines

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      ..........
if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
    {
        time1 = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
        time1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:13];
        time1.tag = tagtime1;
        time1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        if(indexPath.section ==0)
            time1.text =[(Lesson *) [[Singleton sharedInstance].chetNedel.monday objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] time1];
        if(indexPath.section ==1)
            time1.text =[(Lesson *) [[Singleton sharedInstance].chetNedel.tuesday objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] time1];
        if(indexPath.section ==2)
            time1.text =[(Lesson *) [[Singleton sharedInstance].chetNedel.wednesday objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] time1];
        if(indexPath.section ==3)
            time1.text =[(Lesson *) [[Singleton sharedInstance].chetNedel.thirsday objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] time1];
        if(indexPath.section ==4)
            time1.text =[(Lesson *) [[Singleton sharedInstance].chetNedel.friday objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] time1];
        if(indexPath.section ==5)
            time1.text =[(Lesson *) [[Singleton sharedInstance].chetNedel.saturday objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] time1];
        time1.frame = CGRectMake(8, 12, 300-124, 11);
     ...........
 [cell.contentView addSubview:time1];
```

what i do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What error are you getting exactly? Looking at your code however I think the problem happens when you do the removeObjectAtIndex followed by insertObject:atIndex:. After you remove the object, the indexes of the array are recalculated and now you have 1 less object in your array. So if you then do the insertObject:atIndex without decreasing the index where you want to put it, you're not going to end up with it where you want. I suggest you combine both lines into one and use exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex: instead. Here's updated code:

```
    if(fromIndexPath.section==0)
{
   [[Singleton sharedInstance].chetNedel.monday exchangeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row withObjectAtIndex:toIndexPath.row];
}
if(fromIndexPath.section==1)
{
    [[Singleton sharedInstance].chetNedel.tuesday exchangeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row withObjectAtIndex:toIndexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM time1]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600c2f0'

Comment: this error on this line
            time1.text =[(Lesson *) [[Singleton sharedInstance].chetNedel.monday objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] time1];

Comment: it does sound like you could be accessing an array position that has gone out of whack. Did you try combining your removeObjectAtIndex followed by insertObject:atIndex: into one exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex: like I suggested?

Comment: if really I not exactly understand how do this. Can you write example please?

Comment: my english is bad and I not immediately understand what you mind. I do this and all work

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question closely enough. With a second look it says clearly what your problem is. You are trying to call a "time1" method on an array which doesn't have such a method. Does that make sense? Look more closely at the object you are calling time1 on, try to NSLog it and see what it is.

Comment: I've update my answer with code showing the use of exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:.

Answer (score 0):

i don't find your error but i think you must use a custom UITableViewCell instead of add an UILabele at every row...because cell are recycled and time1 may already exist.

Comment: how can I do this? example please

Comment: this link http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-design-a-custom-uitableviewcell-from-scratch/1292/ may help you.